# How can I make that FB TraceManager will save only committed transactions

Tags: c#, database, firebird

Firebird trace manager saves in the file specified at the time of logging in, 
even those query's that do not end up running correctly.

Comment: show some code and effort

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question please add some details.

Comment: if you make a query while fbtracemgr is running, fbtracemgr saves that query in a text file, but always save  a register on that file even the query is wrong, i only want that save when the query its right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebird trace facility pushes information about actions as they happen; it has no memory. Therefor it is not possible to only get those actions that have been committed (because the commit might be an action that happens a lot later).

It might be possible to build that yourself application side, but that will take some development effort from you.